# How to embed Microsoft word file content to a flutter application without rewriting it using Rich text

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ms-word, richtextbox

I'm developing a flutter application for both Android and IOS, I want to embed the content of a Microsoft word file `.docx` or `.doc` provided by the client to be viewed in the about screen of the application.

The file is long and I can't rewrite it using [Rich text widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html). the file is simple and doesn't have images.

I did some research and I found some solution talking about converting the file to pdf and embed a pdf view. I didn't like it also because the content won't be shown as a part of the application and the page separators will still be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After long research, I found [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html) package which is an amazing package that converts your simple `HTML` to a flutter widget and gives you the choice to use it as a webview or just for rendering static Html.

we need now to add this package to `pubspec.yaml`, please always set the [latest version](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html#-installing-tab-)

```
dependencies:
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.3.2+1
```

The challenge now is to convert the word document to simple `HTML` without `js` or external `css` files

I managed to find that free site https://wordhtml.com/ that allows you to paste your word file content to its editor and it will convert it directly to `HTML`

The final step is to copy the content from the `HTML` tab and insert it to a widget

```
const kHtml = """
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>A paragraph with <strong>strong</strong> <em>emphasized</em> text.</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item number one</li>
  <li>
    Two
    <ul>
      <li>2.1 (nested)</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ol>
<p>Thank you</p>
""";

class HelloWorldScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('HelloWorldScreen'),
        ),
        body: HtmlWidget(
          kHtml,
          webView: false,
        ),
      );
}
```

In my case, I want the content to scrollable so I surrounded the HtmlWidget with a listview

```
class HelloWorldScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('HelloWorldScreen'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            HtmlWidget(
                kHtml,
              ),
          ],
        )
      );
}
```

Comment: I also have a similar kind of requirement where I have to show contents of different docs on different pages, and the contents are very long. This is the best solution in my opinion. Neat and clean. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi, it works perfectly for me with text but I have images to be displayed too, any recommendation?

Comment: @ZXERSTON I didn't try the images, But on the package page you can find `IMG with support for asset (asset://), data uri, local file (file://) and network image via cached_network_image. Additional .svg file support via flutter_svg.`

If you have a working answer with image please update the answer